# Making a Release Build in Xcode

Tags: xcode, compilation

I am trying to build a Cocoa app in "Release" mode, but I can't figure out how to do that.  If I select Product -> Build for -> Running, it builds the debug build.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Xcode 4 it is hidden in the [scheme thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402).

Go to `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme…` (or click on the product name on left of the *run* and *stop* buttons and select `Edit Scheme…`). The select in the left table view the *Run* cell and switch to the *Info* tab. There you can select the *build configuration* at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Build for -> Archiving`. The Xcode Organizer will then open, with the Xcode archive of the release version in there.